# creating MACD on seconadry yaxis in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm adding a secondary yaxis using

```
chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
         text: 'MACD'
        },
        top: 360,
        height: 87,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 1,

    });
```

to create MACD by using this

```
chart.addSeries(
    {
        color: '#F20',
        name: 'MACD',
        linkedTo: 'primary',
        showInLegend: true,
        type: 'trendline',
        algorithm: 'MACD',
        yAxis: 1,
        periods:15                                  
    });
```

The MACD was drawn but not in the secondary axis...its was drawn in the baseline.

[image: MACD]

I created a jsfiddle for the same please check http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/EgYFV/

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to specify if its an X or Y axis when creating a new one.

Comment: then what about [http://jsfiddle.net/wvaGt/]    please check this.

Comment: I can't see much of your code, so I can't help you much further than pointing out the differences between your code snippets and theirs, but checking if you are referencing the right yAxis might be an idea.

Comment: In general it should work, but please reproduce your chart as live demo.

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan: Please check with the updated question and also here is the link -> [http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/EgYFV/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use second index of yAxis `yAxis:2`, because 1, it is the navigator yAxis.

http://jsfiddle.net/EgYFV/1/

Comment: thank you very much. Can you tell me one more thing...why the yaxis is re-sizing while adding the secondary yaxis and MACD series?

Comment: Probably it is not enough space, so try to adapt  top / height  parameters